# How to Create a Network Share using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I want to create a network share using vbScript.

Is there a way of doing this other than executing a "net share" command?

e.g.

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run "net share sc1=" & sShare , 1, false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WMI via vbscript.

Taken from http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/filesfolders/sharedfolders/#CreateNetworkShare.htm

```
Creating a Network Share

Creates a shared folder named FinanceShare, setting the maximum number of simultaneous connections to 25, and adding a share description.

Const FILE_SHARE = 0
Const MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS = 25
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objNewShare = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Share")
errReturn = objNewShare.Create _
    ("C:\Finance", "FinanceShare", FILE_SHARE, _
        MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS, "Public share for the Finance group.")
Wscript.Echo errReturn
```

Comment: I found that the folder I was sharing needed a \ on the end to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Dim WshNetwork
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "E:", "\\Server\Public"
```

Taken from this MSDN page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6(VS.85).aspx

It is how we map network shares in our login scripts.

Comment: That's mapping a network share - not creating a network share. But thanks.

Comment: Duh, sorry about that.